# universal destructor in template <class T> when t = int * or t = int

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

Some days ago I wrote a template class which looks like this:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    T ** matrix;
    int n;
    int m;
      .
      .
      .
}
```

And constructor:

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int _n, int _m)
{
      n = _n;
      m = _m;
      matrix = new  T * [n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new T[m];
        }
}
```

And right now I would like to create a destructor like this:

```
template <class T>
aghMatrix<T>::~aghMatrix()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    } 
    }
```

At first I thought it'd solve all problems but I was wrong.
In function `main`:

```
Matrix<int> a; //destructor works find
Matrix<int*>a; //error destructor
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The code you've posted won't even come close to compiling for numerous reasons. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and then copy-paste exactly what error message you're seeing, *error destructor* is meaningless.

Comment: You did not show the code for the default constructor that your example is *actually* calling. You showed code for a constructor that your example is *not* calling (unless your parameters have default values, which you did not show).

Comment: BTW, `delete[] matrix;` is missing... Simplify your life and use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that this is a coding exercise of some kind. For a real world application you should not write your own matrix implementations but rather rely on containers found in the standard library or on one of the many matrix libraries out there.

The example that was posted had several problems and wouldn't even compile. So let me just start by giving a minimal solution:

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {
public:

    Matrix(int _n, int _m)
        : n(_n), m(_m), matrix(new T*[n])  // always initialize your members
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new T[m];
        }
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            delete[] matrix[i];
        }
        delete[] matrix; // this deletes the first level
    }

private:
    int n;
    int m;
    T ** matrix;
};
```

What should be learnt from this is:

- Make sure you initialize every class member in the constructor's 
  initializer list for safety and performance reasons
- Do not forget to delete the memory pointed to by your first level pointers (last line in destructor)
- Do not use explicit `new` and `delete` if you don't have to
- What about copy and move semantics? They are defined but won't do what they should.

In order to make use of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and to avoid explicit `delete` you can use [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead. The equivalent code now looks like this:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class Matrix2 {
public:

    Matrix2(int _n, int _m)
        : n(_n), m(_m), matrix(new T[n * m])
    {}

private:
    int n;
    int m;
    std::unique_ptr<T> matrix;
};
```

Much simpler and less error prone. The unique pointer is now taking care of the resource management. Note that I allocate `n * m` objects of type `T` which means your matrix access operator will look like this:

```
    T operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return matrix.get()[i * n + j];
    }
```

The unique_ptr can be moved but not copied which means you can now safely move `Matrix2` but not copy. Copy semantics must be defined explicitly:

```
    Matrix2(const Matrix2& other)
        : n(other.n),  m(other.m), matrix(new T[n * m])
    {
        std::copy(other.matrix.get(), other.matrix.get() + n * m, matrix.get());
    }

    Matrix2& operator=(const Matrix2& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            n = other.n;
            m = other.m;
            matrix.reset(new T[n * m]);
            std::copy(other.matrix.get(), other.matrix.get() + n * m, matrix.get());
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Note that this code is for demo purposes only and still lacks important aspects and should not be used in a real application.